# Python command line SETUP for ABSOLUTE BEGINNER with Python

Tags: python

I'm "new school" meaning that i've never really used the command prompt(they didn't teach us anything but IDE's in school). I would like to setup Python using Notepad++ for the editor, and winpdb as my debugger.

I want stuff to work really easy from the cmd prompt but it is not.

This is what I put in my System Environment:
C:\PYTHON27;C:\PYTHON27\DLLs;C:\PYTHON27\LIB;C:\PYTHON27\LIB\LIB-TK;C:\PYTHON27\LIB\SITE-PACKAGES;

This is what i want to have happen (but it doesn't work, doesn't load python or the script):
python myscript.py
Then it should run the interpreter.  I'd like it to find my script file wherever it may be.

Can someone baby-step me through this command line setup (the docs expect the user to know how to fluently use the cmd prompt)

I just don't want to have to manually put in path every single time I want to do something

Also I have Console2, I would rather use this than the standard cmd.  How do i get it to have the same functionality that i'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PATH doesn't affect where data files are found. (And your script is a data file as far as Windows is concerned). You should `cd C:\Path\to\folder\with\your\scripts` when you open your command prompt, and then you'll be able to `python myscript.py` from there.

(You might like to make a dedicated shortcut to the command prompt with "Start in" set to your script directory, so you don't have to `cd` every time.)

The same should apply to Console2.